# three.js perspectiveCamera + orbitControl how I can get current "zoom" level?

Tags: javascript, three.js, zooming, perspectivecamera

I try to detect current zoom level ( or something like this ) in Three.js scene. 
 I mean "zoom" (dolly) applied by mouse wheel action 
for example: simple scene contain : perspectiveCamera + orbitControl + object

[1:](http://jsfiddle.net/denis_miroshnikov_ts/7teqkspu/77/) `<= test is here

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.dollyOut = function(){    }
controls.dollyIn = function(){    }

controls.addEventListener('change', renderlog); ....`
```

TNX

Comment: You should add your code in your question instead of a link to it. Editing it you can use the code snippet editor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are using a `PerspectiveCamera` in combination with `OrbitControls`, you have to be aware that "zooming" is not as a variable as it is with a orthographic camera. Instead "zooming" is done by just placing the camera closer to the target.

This means you can get the zoom distance by calculating the distance between the target and the camera position.

```
var zoom = controls.target.distanceTo( controls.object.position )
```

Comment: Perspective Camera with Orbit Control when zoomed it does not change position of camera , it changed projection ( I think )

Comment: But maybe you right : http://jsfiddle.net/denis_miroshnikov_ts/7teqkspu/92/ look at the console

Comment: only with an orthographic it changes the projection, with an perspective camera it changes the position